# Linked List size()

Tags: java, tree

I need to implement a size() on these two classes and not really sure how to begin:

```
interface Tree extends Cloneable { 
    int size(); 
}

class Fruit implements Tree {

    @Override public int size() { 

    }
}

class Branch implements Tree {

    private List<Tree> children = new LinkedList<Tree>();
    public List<Tree> getChildren() { 
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children); 
    }

    public void addChild(Tree tree) { 
        children.add(tree); 
    }

    @Override public int size() { 

    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on how to create these two size() methods? I need them to calculates the number of actual fruits in a tree.

Comment: That isn't a linked list. That's a tree.

Comment: public class Fruit implements Tree{
 @Override public int size() {
  return this.size(); 
  
 }
}


public class Branch implements Tree{
 private List<Tree> children = new LinkedList<Tree>();
 public List<Tree> getChildren() { return Collections.unmodifiableList(children); }
 public void addChild(Tree tree) { children.add(tree); }
 @Override public int size() {
  return this.getChildren().size(); 

 }

}

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is homework? ;)

How about

```
@Override public int size() { 
    int size = 0;
    for(Tree tree: children) size += tree.size();
    return size;
}
```

Comment: I left the implementation for Fruit as an exercise. I can't do all his homework ;) I assumed "number of actual fruits in a tree." means only Fruit and not Branches should be counted.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I was thinking he wanted to count nodes, didn't look that closely at the question.

Comment: so for Fruit would I do something as simple as: return this.size();

Comment: How many fruit in a Fruit? Without more detail, I would assume you want `return 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Linked list operations are typically done in a recursive fashion, where every node has this definition for size:

```
@Override
public int size(){
     // Don't forget the base case! (if there is no child)
     return (child != null) ? 1 + child.size() : 1;
}
```

The call, `rootNode.size()`, recursively sums 1 for every node of the linked list and eventually returns size to the original caller.